# Libcurl / C. Запись результата в переменную.

Tags: c, php, webbrowser

Собственно, нужна функция, которая будет возвращать результат. Возвращенные данные будут записаны в переменную и дальше обработаны.

Ни в какую не хочет записывать, постоянно просто выводит на экран.

Аналога `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, как в php, нет?

Как реализовать задачу?

Мой код: http://code.wen.ru/ibBHZze Выводит содержимое на экран =(

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

CURLcode open_html(char url[])
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode buffer;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        buffer = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
    CURLcode result;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    printf("Привет1n");

    open_html("http://visavi.net");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Нельзя ли увидеть, как именно Вы пытались это реализовать?

Comment: Посмотрите опцию CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION. Это callback, который вызывается libcurl для записи файла. Если Вы его напишите так, чтобы он запоминал данные в памяти вместо записи в файл, то...

Comment: Так, сделал callback. Теперь как бы мне вывести тип CURLcode на экран?

Comment: @Антон Малюта, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Прочитайте про [`curl_easy_recv`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_recv.html): надо выставить опцию `CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY` перед вызовом `curl_easy_perform`, тогда он только установит соединение, а данные в `buffer` примет `curl_easy_recv`.

Comment: Пишет: 'CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY' undeclared

Answer (score 1):

Возможно я что-то неправильно понял, но вот Ваш пример с моими правками.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

static char *buf;

size_t cb (char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
    int l = strlen(buf);
    char *buf1 = malloc(l+size*nmemb+1);
    strcpy(buf1, buf);
    free(buf);
    memmove(buf1+l, ptr, size*nmemb);
    buf1[l+size*nmemb] = 0;
    buf=buf1;
    return size*nmemb;
}

void open_html(char url[])
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode buffer;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, cb);
        buffer = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

int main()
{
    buf=malloc(1);
    *buf=0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    printf("Привет1n");

    open_html("http://visavi.net");
    printf("***\n%s\n***", buf);
    free(buf);

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

UPD: ответ обновлён

Comment: 5+!
Только вот единственное но, выводит не всю страницу на экран, как этого избежать?

Comment: Накапливайте куски в callback-функции. Приведённый вариант затирает все куски, кроме последнего. Те, кто посмотрит внимательно, заметят, что эти куски ещё и не освобождаются по free...
Один из вариантов в обновлённом ответе. (обратить внимание на strlen и strcpy -- в странице должны быть текстовые, а не двоичные данные)